# UEFI fails to boot Windows 8 from live usb

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8, boot, usb, uefi

I've burned windows 8 image on my usb using dd. There all files like boot efi bootmgr etc. on it. When i press Esc during boot, there comes a menu with 3 options: Ubuntu, UEFI Sony, Enter setup. When i choose UEFI Sony(potential windows), menu disappears for a second and pops up again. If i change boot priority in UEFI, making my usb #1, computer tries to boot Windows for some time, then ignores it and starts ubuntu. I suspect that i am doing completely wrong, but i've wasted the whole day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest ISOs provided by Microsoft do *not* work with any of the traditional tools. Quoting from the MKUB community wiki:

> It was not possible to extract the content from the Windows iso file directly to a USB pendrive. **The files were not copied correctly (with any of the standard copying tools: cp, rsync, dd)** in Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS (the current Ubuntu version, when this feature was added to mkusb-nox). But it works in a reliable way to extract to a tarfile, and then extract from the tarfile to the USB pendrive.

So, the easy solution is to use that exact same tool (tested successfully): [MKUSB](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb) (for Ubuntu and derivatives, may also work in Debian and derivatives).

**Installation:**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mkusb/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mkusb mkusb-nox usb-pack-efi
```

[Special usage instructions for "Windows USB install drive"](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb#Windows_USB_install_drive)

Answer (score 0):

We can try to reboot windows 8 from live USB according to the following article.
If it still does not work, maybe there is something wrong with the UEFI Bootable USB drive, we can recreate the UEFI Bootable USB Flash Drive refer the same article.

**This article contains three parts:**

UEFI Bootable USB Drive Guide Requirements

UEFI Bootable USB Drive Guide

UEFI Booting in Windows 8

[How To Make UEFI Bootable USB Flash Drive to Install Windows 8](https://www.servethehome.com/uefi-bootable-usb-drive-windows-8-windows-server-2012/)